# How to change plot window size in image.plot (fields)

Tags: r, plot, field

I am using `image.plot` from the `fields` package to plot maps. The maps all have different dimensions/numbers of pixels and I would like to plot each on the same scale, i.e. that the second plot in the example below is twice the size of the first

```
a <- matrix(rnorm(100), 10, 10)  
b <- matrix(rnorm(200), 20, 10)
image.plot(seq(1, 10), seq(1, 10), a, asp =1)
image.plot(seq(1, 20), seq(1, 10), b, asp =1)
```

Thanks